# pymysql - Clear a table for testing

Tags: python, mysql, testing, pymysql

I'm looking to write tests for my application. I would like to work with a clean database for all my tests. For various reasons, I cannot create a separate test database.

What I currently do is run everything in a transaction and never commit to the db. However some tests read from the db, so I'd like to delete all rows at the start of the transaction and start from there.

The problem I am running into is with foreign key constraints. Currently I just go through each table and do

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM %s" % tablename)
```

which gives me

```
IntegrityError: (1451, u'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
foreign key constraint fails (`testing`.`app_adjust_reason`,
CONSTRAINT `app_adjust_reason_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`adjust_reason_id`)
REFERENCES `adjust_reason` (`id`))')
```

edit: I would like something generic that could be applied to any database. Otherwise I would specifically drop the constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general approach is to create a database from scratch before the test run and drop it after, use `CREATE DATABASE_NAME` and `DROP DATABASE_NAME`. This way, you are always starting with a clean database state and you would not worry about the foreign key or other constraints.

Note that you would also need to create your table schema and (possibly test data) after you create a database.

As a real world example, this is what Django does when you run your tests. The table schema is recreated by the Django ORM from your models, then the [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) or/and the [schema](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/) and [data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) migrations are applied.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to copy the schema from one database into a newly created testing database?

Comment: @Shatnerz are you using any ORM, sqlalchemy, for example? This usually makes thing easier when it comes to duplicating/recreating your project database schema for testing reasons..

Comment: @Shatnerz a naive idea though would be to export your working schema to an sql file and import it to your test database schema.

Comment: unfortunately we are using a very primitive, in-house "ORM" that is lacking. In the past I have used sqlalchemy, which made life incredibly easy.